# For which numbers is the matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the matrix \begin{equation*}A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

I want to find for which real numbers $a,b,c,d$ the matrix is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and for which in $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$.

The charachteristic polynomial is \begin{align*}\det (A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda +(ad-cb)\end{align*}

So, the eigenvalues are
\begin{align*}\lambda^2&-(a+d)\lambda +(ad-cb)=0 \\  \Rightarrow &\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{(a+d)\pm \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4(ad-cb)}}{2}=\frac{(a+d)\pm \sqrt{a^2+2ad+d^2-4ad+4cb}}{2}\\ & =\frac{(a+d)\pm \sqrt{a^2-2ad+d^2+4cb}}{2}  =\frac{(a+d)\pm \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4cb}}{2}\end{align*}

We have the following cases:

As an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\times 2}$ we have the following:

- Expression under the root $< 0$: no real eigenvalue, so the matrix is not diagonalizable.
- Expression under the root $> 0$: two different eigenvalues, that means that the matrix is not diagonalizable, or not?
- Expression under the root $= 0$, we have an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$. What do we have in this case?

As an element of $\mathbb{C}^{\times 2}$ we have the following:

- Expression under the root $\neq 0$: two different eigenvalues , that means that the matrix is not diagonalizable, right?
- Expression under the root $= 0$, we have an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$. What do we have in this case?

Comment: Two different eigenvalues implies diagonalizable. If you have both the same value for the eigenvalue, it means that $$\chi_{A}\left(X\right)=\left(X-a\right)^2$$ hence if it was diagonalizable you would have $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=aI_2$ then $A=aI_2$ that's the only case where it will be diagonalizable.

Comment: So, can we not get a further condition that has to be satisfied so that we know when the matrix is diagonizable in the case of two same eigenvalues? @Atmos

Comment: At condition (2) it says that it has to have at least n real roots, if it has n complex eigenvalues, what does then hold? @Moo

Comment: I haven't really understood why in general, if a matrix has
complex eigenvalues, it is not diagonalizable. Coudyou explain it further to me? @Moo

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimum polynomial is a product of simple linear factors.

Also, the distinct roots of the minimum polynomial are the same as the distinct eigenvalues of the matrix.

So for a 2x2 matrix, the only case when it is NOT diagonalizable is when the matrix has 2 repeated eigenvalues.

The matrix has repeated eigenvalues when:

$$det(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^2-\lambda \cdot (a+d) + (ad-bc)$$
has repeated roots....ie: $b^2-4ac=0$, which should simplify to: $$(a-d)^2+4bc=0$$

So all values of a, b, c and d that satisfy $(a-d)^2+4bc\ne0$ make A diagonalizable.

Comment: If the matrix has repeated eigenvalues then its characteristic polynomial is $(x-\alpha )^2$ where $\alpha$ is the eigenvalue. The matrix can still be diagonalizable in this case, but this requires further analysis.

Comment: So my solution doesn't hold only when A is a diagonal matrix and with both its diagonal elements being the same. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, because this is the only case when the matrix with repeated eigenvalue has two dimensional eigenspace. Perhaps a minor special case, but nonetheless a necessary addition.

Comment: I got stuck right now. When a 2x2 matrix has two repeated eigenvalues, the matrix is diagonalizable only when the the eigenvectors are independent? @Dave

Comment: The dimension of the eigenspace must equal the algebraic multiplicity of the repeated eigenvalue. In the $2\times 2$ cases this means that the dimension of the eigenspace must be $2$, and this means there are $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Ah ok! Can we say that this happens when a condition for $a,b,c,d$ holds? Or do we have just to say that the eigenvalues have to be independent?  @Dave

Comment: In the repeated eigenvalue case: the matrix is diagonalizable if and only if $c=b=0$.

Comment: Ah, so if $c=0$ and $b\neq 0$ or other way around the matrix is not diagonizable, right? Why do both have to be equal to $0$ ? @Dave

Comment: This is in the repeated eigenvalue case: $b=c=0$ means that $A$ is a diagonal matrix, which as in many of the previous comments, is the only case when $A$ is diagonalizable. If the eigenvalue is repeated and $b\neq 0$ or $c\neq 0$ then the dimension of the eigenspace of this eigenvalue is equal to $1$, and this is less than the algebraic multiplicity $2$, so the matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Ah ok! Why is the multiplicity less than 2 when one of b or c id different from 0? And I have also an other question... Does this hold also at the case $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$ or just  at the case $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ ? @Dave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72012/discussion-between-dave-and-mary-star).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix can be diagonalised iff it has a complete set of eigenvectors.

To be more explicit for a $2\times2$ matrix we can distinguish a few cases:

1. If the two eigenvalues are distinct, which occurs when $(a-d)^2+4bc\neq0$, then the eigenvectors are linearly independent, and the matrix can be diagonalised.
2. If the eigenvalues are identical (degenerate), one needs to check if the eigenvectors are linearly dependent. The degenerate condition requires $(a-d)^2+4bc = 0$, and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = (a-d)/2$. The equations for the eigenvector(s) $\mathbf{x} = (x,y)$ are therefore
   \begin{align}
      \begin{cases}
     \frac{a-d}{2} x + b y = 0 \\
     c x - \frac{a-d}{2} y = 0
   \end{cases}
   \end{align}
   These equations are linearly dependent because of the degeneracy condition, so there are two possibilities:

   - We can determine no relation between $x$ and $y$, and therefore two eigenvectors exist (we can choose any linearly independent pair). This can occur only if *all* coefficients of the eigenvectors system of equations vanish, i.e. $(a-d) = b = c = 0$. The matrix in this cases reduces to the (already diagonal) form
     \begin{equation}
     A = \begin{bmatrix}
      a & 0 \\
     0 & a
     \end{bmatrix}
     \end{equation}
   - As soon as one of the coefficients of the eigenvectors equations does not vanish, we establish a relation between $x$ and $y$, thus choosing one specific direction for the (only) eigenvector. As a consequence the matrix is defective and not diagonalisable. This can manifest in two forms:

     - If $(a-d)=0$ then we must have that either $b=0$ or $c=0$, because we still must satisfy the degenerate condition $(a-d)^2+4bc = 0$. In this case the matrix has the form
       \begin{equation}
       A = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
       0 & a
       \end{bmatrix} \mbox{ with } b\neq0 \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad  
       A = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & 0 \\
       c & a
       \end{bmatrix} \mbox{ with } c\neq0.
       \end{equation}
       which are classic non-diagonalisable Jordan blocks.
     - If $(a-d)\neq0$ then, for  $(a-d)^2+4bc = 0$ to hold, we must have that both $b\neq0$ and $c\neq0$. Also in this case there exist only one eigenvector, and the matrix is non-diagonalisable. An example of such a matrix is

\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 5 & 1 \\
-4 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}